# Can a Synchronized Block be simplified to a Try-Finally Block on the Bytecode Level?

Tags: java, bytecode, synchronized, try-finally, jvm-bytecode

Writing my own compiler for a Java-like language, I am having trouble compiling `synchronized blocks`. I come up with the following idea to simplify them to `try-finally` blocks:

```
synchonized (obj) {
     statements...
}
```

Can be replaced with

```
Object _lock = obj
_monitorEnter(lock)
try {
    statements...
}
finally {
    _monitorExit(lock)
}
```

Where `_monitorEnter` and `_monitorExit` represent the `MONITORENTER` and `MONITOREXIT` instructions.

Am I correct with this assumption of how `synchronized` is compiled, or am I missing something?

***EDIT***

My implementation previously had some special handling for `return` and `throw` statements within the body. Basically, it would manually load all `lock` variables and `MONITOREXIT` them before each `*RETURN` or `THROW` instruction. Is this handled by the `finally` block, or do I still need these checks?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. In fact, this is the _exact_ syntax for [`java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html).

Comment: I’m not sure whether I understand your idea. If you are the one who implements the compiler, replacing `synchronized` by `try … finally` doesn’t simplify anything as you are still the one who has to implement `try … finally` then, aren’t you? So you still have to care for any `return` statement by yourself.

Comment: @Holger sure, but I would have to implement the same thing twice, so there is twice as many ways to make a mistake. Currently, the synchronized byte code generation is just a specialization of a try/finally statement.

Comment: So it’s more a matter of treating them equally rather than substituting one for another. Actually, both, `synchronized` and `finally`, are constructs without an equivalent on the byte code level, but the same kind of workaround. Generally, when trying to develop a compiler for the JVM, it’s strongly recommended to know the entire [“Compiling for the Java Virtual Machine”](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-3.html) chapter (if not the entire JVM spec)…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assumptions are correct. The `synchronized` block in the Java language is implemented with `monitorenter` and `monitorexit` instructions. You can review the JVM specification details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.14).

> Synchronization in the Java Virtual Machine is implemented by monitor
>   entry and exit, either explicitly (by use of the monitorenter and
>   monitorexit instructions) or implicitly (by the method invocation and
>   return instructions).

The compiler generates bytecode that will handle all exceptions thrown inside a `synchronized` body, so your try-finally approach will work fine here.

[Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.13) of `finally` statement does not tell anything about releasing monitors. Example provided in the first link shows bytecode for a simple method wrapped in `synchronized` block. As you can see, any possible exception is handled to ensure monitorexit instruction execution. You should implement same behaviour in your compiler (write code that will release monitor inside finally statement).

```
void onlyMe(Foo f) {
    synchronized(f) {
        doSomething();
    }
}

Method void onlyMe(Foo)
0   aload_1             // Push f
1   dup                 // Duplicate it on the stack
2   astore_2            // Store duplicate in local variable 2
3   monitorenter        // Enter the monitor associated with f
4   aload_0             // Holding the monitor, pass this and...
5   invokevirtual #5    // ...call Example.doSomething()V
8   aload_2             // Push local variable 2 (f)
9   monitorexit         // Exit the monitor associated with f
10  goto 18             // Complete the method normally
13  astore_3            // In case of any throw, end up here
14  aload_2             // Push local variable 2 (f)
15  monitorexit         // Be sure to exit the monitor!
16  aload_3             // Push thrown value...
17  athrow              // ...and rethrow value to the invoker
18  return              // Return in the normal case
Exception table:
From    To      Target      Type
4       10      13          any
13      16      13          any
```

Answer (score 0):

The Java compiler compiles synchronized blocks to something much like a try-finally, as you guessed. However, there is one minor difference - the exception handling catches exceptions thrown by `monitorexit` and loops infinitely trying to release the lock. There's no way to specify control flow quite like this in Java.

Comment: Yeah, possibly looping infinitely on an exception is a great feature though I’m not sure whether this really is mandatory, just because it appears in one example code of the specification…